# Fixing Cross site scripting vulnerability in java using OWASP

Tags: java, xss, esapi

I am working on fixing Cross site scripting issues in java.Since i am new to OWASP, could someone please help me to figure out how to use OWASP in below  cases to sanitize inputs.

1. `Enumeration<String> EnumHeader = request.getHeaderNames();`
2. `Map<String, String[]> pMap = request.getParameterMap();`
3. `Object value = request.getHeader(key);`
4. `String[] refs = (req.getParameterValues(REFS_NAME));`

Comment: I would start by following rule #0 and rule #1 at: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: @fgb provided link is old. See https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html. But it indeed should be the starting point for all XSS discussions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While data validation can be very helpful in preventing XSS, it doesn't necessarily cover all the bases for persistent XSS. The only 100% effective protection is proper contextual output encoding as offered by the OWASP Java Encoder Project, or OWASP ESAPI's Encoder. One reason for this is for persistent XSS, the tainted data can come from a DB that might be entered or altered by another application that has insert / update access to those same DB tables but which is NOT doing proper data validation. (That is, the tainted data could enter into your system in some other manner than through your application.) So the only foolproof solution is to do proper contextual output encoding. The OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet that you have already been pointed to is a great place to start that explains all of that.

Comment: How could I prevent XSS issue for java objects

Comment: @unknown_11 - You will need to provide more details for us to provide further assistance as XSS defense is very nuanced. Until then, I can only give a generic answer like "use CSP headers and appropriate contextual output encoding". As fgb mentioned earlier though, I would refer you to the OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet at https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html as a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an OS library to sanitize those Strings/Objects.

Example library: https://finn-no.github.io/xss-html-filter/

Then for those collections of headers and parameters you could iterate through them using Java 8 Streams, and map them to new filtered collections (that use the sanitizer library).

Comment: The approach of that library, using regex to replace strings in the html, can produce vulnerable malformed html. The owasp html sanitizer is better. For example, this executes an alert: `<a href='&#60;/a&#x3e;&#39;&#60;script&#x3e;alert(1)&#x3c;/script&#x3e;'>123</a><a href='&#60;/a&#x3e;&#39;&#60;script&#x3e;alert(1)&#x3c;/script&#x3e;'>123</a>`

Comment: Indeed, the HTML filter referenced here has the specific use case that your application has to accept HTML content from users--by default it could make you MORE vulnerable, especially if you're not doing output escaping.  As @fgb also points out, the correct way to sanitize HTML is with an HTML parser, NOT regex.

Comment: Trying to address XSS vulnerabilities by using an interceptor approach such as a JavaEE Servlet Filter or a Spring Interceptor is bound to fail. It is an anti-pattern. I wrote about this anti-pattern on our ESAPI GitHub wiki. For details, see https://github.com/ESAPI/esapi-java-legacy/wiki/XSS-Defense:-No-Silver-Bullets. That said, xss-html-filter is a sanitizer rather than an output encoder. It seems more like a naive OWASP HTML Sanitizer or OWASP AntiSamy. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Cross site scripting can be fixed by encoding the parameter and also by validating the parameter with a customized regex.

For example: Encode.forhtml(inputparam)

There are serveral types of context based encoding using OWASP encoder. if your not sure about encoder or validation pattern, try the below cross site scripting validator to make sure the working(right) fix approach.

XSS validator for java: http://fixforscrossite.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/